# Use CASE ON LIKE JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-like

I would like to use a `CASE` statement in conjunction with a `LIKE LEFT JOIN` on tblAssets. I am having trouble using a `LIKE` after `THEN` on my case statement. Below I have two separate queries which work. I need to use the first query for multiple case scenarios as in the second query, but joining when they are like each other . Can this be done?

**1st query**

```
SELECT tblAssets.AssetName, tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME
FROM tblDBFeedImport
LEFT JOIN tblAssets 
ON tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME LIKE + '%' + tblAssets.AssetName + '%'
```

**2nd query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblAssets.AssetID, tblAssets.AssetName, tblAssets.LS2Name, tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME, tblDBFeedImport.FACILITY_NAME, tblAssets.PipelineStatusID
FROM tblDBFeedImport

LEFT JOIN tblAssets
ON tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME = 
CASE
    WHEN tblAssets.AssetName LIKE '%' + tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME + '%' THEN tblAssets.AssetName
    WHEN tblAssets.LS2Name LIKE '%' + tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME + '%' THEN tblAssets.LS2Name
    END

WHERE 1=1
AND tblAssets.PipelineStatusID=6
ORDER BY tblAssets.AssetName, tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME, tblAssets.LS2Name
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I uderstood, but it seems that you do not need the `CASE` statement, only to add the conditions separated by `OR`: `tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME LIKE + '%' + tblAssets.AssetName + '%' OR tblDBFeedImport.DEAL_SRC_NAME LIKE + '%' + tblAssets.LS2Name + '%'`

Comment: Please not that using like with leading wildcards renders this nonSARGable and any indexes are left useless as it will be forced to do a full scan.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `ON` clause.

Comment: What does " I am having trouble" mean?    Do you get an error message, and if so, what is the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the CASE to generate a number, then check on that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 ass.AssetID, ass.AssetName, ass.LS2Name, 
 imp.DEAL_SRC_NAME, imp.FACILITY_NAME, 
 ass.PipelineStatusID
FROM tblDBFeedImport imp
LEFT JOIN tblAssets ass
ON CASE
   WHEN ass.AssetName LIKE '%' + imp.DEAL_SRC_NAME + '%' THEN 1
   WHEN ass.LS2Name LIKE '%' + imp.DEAL_SRC_NAME + '%' THEN 2
   ELSE 0
   END > 0
WHERE ass.PipelineStatusID = 6
ORDER BY ass.AssetName, imp.DEAL_SRC_NAME, ass.LS2Name
```

But using an OR for this could be faster

```
...
LEFT JOIN tblAssets ass
ON (   ass.AssetName LIKE '%' + imp.DEAL_SRC_NAME + '%' 
    OR ass.LS2Name LIKE '%' + imp.DEAL_SRC_NAME + '%')
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the OR as it was simple, but I suppose the CASE would work too and it would be good to see which option was used for each record in the join.

Comment: Good that it helped you :)  Btw, you probably are already aware, but maybe it's usefull to mention this.  A `CASE` works like a switch.  It breaks out of the checks at the first condition starting from the top that's true.  So if the conditions of both 1 & 2 would be true, it'll still return 1.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware.